# Angular services injector

Tags: angular

When I inject services inside a service, which `injector` this service is using? For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
   contructor(private a: AService, private b: BService)
}
```

If I'm injecting the `MyService` inside a component that declares these services in the component `providers` it will use the component injector?

Comment: It'll use the component injector, which is different from module injector. See here https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components